# Cucumber feature on form with Captcha

Tags: ruby, cucumber, captcha, bdd, ruby-on-rails-3

If you form has captcha (i'm using humanizer gem). How do you fill up form and send and get the expected result when writing cucumber feature.

```
Scenario: Sign Up with Valid Data
  Given I am not authenticated
  And I am on the sign in page
  When I follow "Sign up"
  And I fill in the following:
    | Name                   | Administrator            |    
    | Email                  | admin@admin.com          |
    | Password               | 123456                   |
    | Password confirmation  | 123456                   |
  And I fill in the captcha correctly
  And I press "Sign Up"
  Then I should be on the new_company page
  And I should see "Hello Manoj"
```

Now i can write a step definition matching /^I fill up catcha correctly$/ but what must be put there?

Be gentle, i'm new to cucumber and it's been frustrating so far. I'm not new to Rails or programming otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, Aditya. Putting environment dependent code in models is not good solution. But you can "stub" `bypass_humanizer?` when needed:

```
# user.rb
class User
  include Humanizer

  require_human_on :create, :unless => :bypass_humanizer?

  protected

  def bypass_humanizer?
    false
  end
end

# step definitions for your scenarion
And /^I fill in the captcha correctly$/ do
  # from now any instance of User class will skip require_human_on validator
  User.any_instance.stubs(:bypass_humanizer?).returns(true)
end

# in Gemfile
group :development, :test do
  gem "mocha"
end
```

Now you have a model with environment agnostic code and you can put it in the specific state any time you need (for testing, of course).

Answer (score 2):

So one solution i found out was to ensure Captcha is only added in Production environment.

To some extent i'm happy with that. But it would be ideal to reduce environment based branching in the app.

```
class User
  ...
  include Humanizer
  if Rails.env.production?
    require_human_on :create, :unless => :bypass_humanizer
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yes, it is the most reasonable solution. Just imagine a definition for step "And I fill in captcha correctly" :-)

Comment: You not disable it in test only? That way captcha works locally and on staging.